How can I resolve this "Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1004"
I'm running into the following error trying to work through the transfer hook docs. https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-hook
I am using Ubuntu on Windows WSL:
I am running on local-host using solana-test-validator
Here is the code. (It's the same as the example code with the program_id changed to match my pubkey from transfer_hook-key_pair.json in target/deploy.)
use anchor_lang::{
    prelude::*,
    system_program::{create_account, CreateAccount},
};
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token_interface::{transfer_checked, Mint, TokenAccount, TokenInterface, TransferChecked},
};
use spl_tlv_account_resolution::{
    account::ExtraAccountMeta, seeds::Seed, state::ExtraAccountMetaList,
};
use spl_transfer_hook_interface::instruction::{ExecuteInstruction, TransferHookInstruction};

// transfer-hook program that charges a SOL fee on token transfer
// use a delegate and wrapped SOL because signers from initial transfer are not accessible

declare_id!("AamSC7zh1r4dvHCJS1ofTTiXADqEHCuB2L26aMbNNyAi");

#[program]
pub mod transfer_hook {

    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_extra_account_meta_list(
        ctx: Context<InitializeExtraAccountMetaList>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // index 0-3 are the accounts required for token transfer (source, mint, destination, owner)
        // index 4 is address of ExtraAccountMetaList account
        // The `addExtraAccountsToInstruction` JS helper function resolving incorrectly
        let account_metas = vec![
            // index 5, wrapped SOL mint
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_pubkey(&ctx.accounts.wsol_mint.key(), false, false)?,
            // index 6, token program
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_pubkey(&ctx.accounts.token_program.key(), false, false)?,
            // index 7, associated token program
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_pubkey(
                &ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.key(),
                false,
                false,
            )?,
            // index 8, delegate PDA
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_seeds(
                &[Seed::Literal {
                    bytes: "delegate".as_bytes().to_vec(),
                }],
                false, // is_signer
                true,  // is_writable
            )?,
            // index 9, delegate wrapped SOL token account
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_external_pda_with_seeds(
                7, // associated token program index
                &[
                    Seed::AccountKey { index: 8 }, // owner index (delegate PDA)
                    Seed::AccountKey { index: 6 }, // token program index
                    Seed::AccountKey { index: 5 }, // wsol mint index
                ],
                false, // is_signer
                true,  // is_writable
            )?,
            // index 10, sender wrapped SOL token account
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_external_pda_with_seeds(
                7, // associated token program index
                &[
                    Seed::AccountKey { index: 3 }, // owner index
                    Seed::AccountKey { index: 6 }, // token program index
                    Seed::AccountKey { index: 5 }, // wsol mint index
                ],
                false, // is_signer
                true,  // is_writable
            )?
        ];

        // calculate account size
        let account_size = ExtraAccountMetaList::size_of(account_metas.len())? as u64;
        // calculate minimum required lamports
        let lamports = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(account_size as usize);

        let mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[
            b"extra-account-metas",
            &mint.as_ref(),
            &[ctx.bumps.extra_account_meta_list],
        ]];

        // create ExtraAccountMetaList account
        create_account(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateAccount {
                    from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.to_account_info(),
                },
            )
            .with_signer(signer_seeds),
            lamports,
            account_size,
            ctx.program_id,
        )?;

        // initialize ExtraAccountMetaList account with extra accounts
        ExtraAccountMetaList::init::<ExecuteInstruction>(
            &mut ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.try_borrow_mut_data()?,
            &account_metas,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn transfer_hook(ctx: Context<TransferHook>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
       let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[b"delegate", &[ctx.bumps.delegate]]];
       msg!("Transfer WSOL using delegate PDA");

        // transfer WSOL from sender to delegate token account using delegate PDA
        transfer_checked(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                TransferChecked {
                    from: ctx.accounts.sender_wsol_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.wsol_mint.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.delegate_wsol_token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: ctx.accounts.delegate.to_account_info(),
                },
            )
            .with_signer(signer_seeds),
            amount,
            ctx.accounts.wsol_mint.decimals,
        )?;
        Ok(())
    }

    // fallback instruction handler as workaround to anchor instruction discriminator check
    pub fn fallback<'info>(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>],
        data: &[u8],
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let instruction = TransferHookInstruction::unpack(data)?;

        // match instruction discriminator to transfer hook interface execute instruction  
        // token2022 program CPIs this instruction on token transfer
        match instruction {
            TransferHookInstruction::Execute { amount } => {
                let amount_bytes = amount.to_le_bytes();

                // invoke custom transfer hook instruction on our program
                __private::__global::transfer_hook(program_id, accounts, &amount_bytes)
            }
            _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData.into()),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeExtraAccountMetaList<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account, must use these seeds
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    pub wsol_mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// Order of accounts matters for this struct.
// The first 4 accounts are the accounts required for token transfer (source, mint, destination, owner)
// Remaining accounts are the extra accounts required from the ExtraAccountMetaList account
// These accounts are provided via CPI to this program from the token2022 program
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferHook<'info> {
    #[account(
        token::mint = mint, 
        token::authority = owner,
    )]
    pub source_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        token::mint = mint,
    )]
    pub destination_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK: source token account owner, can be SystemAccount or PDA owned by another program
    pub owner: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub wsol_mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"delegate"], 
        bump
    )]
    pub delegate: SystemAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        token::mint = wsol_mint, 
        token::authority = delegate,
    )]
    pub delegate_wsol_token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        token::mint = wsol_mint, 
        token::authority = owner,
    )]
    pub sender_wsol_token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
}

Steps:
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/transfer_hook.so
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --transfer-hook AamSC7zh1r4dvHCJS1ofTTiXADqEHCuB2L26aMbNNyAi
spl-token create-account 6uHeWR7tMt7TBAGcPhmRvTBpYJqSDfh6UcAVe4D7zrNX
Now when I run:
spl-transfer-hook create-extra-metas AamSC7zh1r4dvHCJS1ofTTiXADqEHCuB2L26aMbNNyAi 6uHeWR7tMt7TBAGcPhmRvTBpYJqSDfh6UcAVe4D7zrNX
I get:
error: send transaction: error: send transaction: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1004 [6 log messages]
From some research I believe 0x1004 indicates mismatched program ID declaration. I've triple checked that the program id matches the key-pair.json pubkey as well as the output of solana program deploy. So I'm a bit lost here. I also can't seem to find a way to actually read the "6 log messages" I've trying looking through the docs to see where those log messages would be without any luck. Any help here would be appreciated.

Looking at the sample transfer hook program at https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/spl/transfer-hook/programs/transfer-hook/src/lib.rs, you need to properly declare the instruction discriminator the instructions:
    #[interface(spl_transfer_hook_interface::initialize_extra_account_meta_list)]
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, metas: Vec<AnchorExtraAccountMeta>) -> Result<()> {

And
    #[interface(spl_transfer_hook_interface::execute)]
    pub fn execute(ctx: Context<Execute>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {


Hey, I decided to write my Transfer Hook without Anchor. I appreciate your response and I will go back and try your suggestion in a few days.
